# matplotlib: Have axis maintaining ratio

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am new to [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/), and I have a very simple (I'm guessing) question.

I have some data that need to be represented in a rectangle of 50x70 "units" (they're feet, actually representing a room) but I don't seem to be able to get matplotlib drawing a rectangle with the same scale on both axis and keeping the 50x70 "dimensions" at the same time.

I've tried the following:

```
import json
import matplotlib
import os
import sys
import traceback
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

DATA_FILE = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "results.json")
FLOOR_DIMENSIONS = (50, 70)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        DATA_FILE = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
    print "Gonna see what happens with file %s" % DATA_FILE
    try:
        with open(DATA_FILE, 'r') as f:
            result_dict = json.load(f)
    except (IOError, OSError, ValueError), e:
        print "Received %s %s when trying to parse json from %s\n"\
        "Showing traceback: %s" % (type(e), e, DATA_FILE, traceback.format_exc())
        result_dict = {}    
    for d_mac in result_dict:
        data = result_dict[d_mac]
        if len(data) < 3:
            continue
        x_s = list(d['x'] for d in data)
        y_s  = list(d['y'] for d in data)
        plt.scatter(x_s, y_s, marker='o', c=numpy.random.rand(5,1), s=15)
    plt.xlim([0, FLOOR_DIMENSIONS[0]])
    plt.ylim([0, FLOOR_DIMENSIONS[1]])
    #plt.axis('equal')
    plt.show()
    sys.exit(0)
```

Doing that, I get:

[image]

Which draws my data inside an square, changing the X-Y scale (X is 50 points, and Y is 70, therefor Y shows "shrunk")

Another option I tried was uncommenting the line saying `plt.axis('equal')`, but that "cuts" the Y axis (doesn't start in 0 and finishes in 70, but starts in 15 and ends in 55, probably because there's no data with *y < 15* and y > 55)

[image]

But I don't want that either, I want the "canvas" starting in Y=0 and ending in Y=70, and if there's no data just show an empty space.

What I need is to draw something like this:

[image]

which I got by manually re-sizing the window where the plot was rendered **:-D**

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `plt.axis('scaled')`.

**edit**: `axis('image')` may be better for your needs.

More axis settings can be found in [the documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qBD2.png).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xs = np.arange(50)
ys = (np.random.random(50)*70) + 15

plt.scatter(xs,ys)

plt.axis('image')
plt.axis([0, 50, 0, 70])

plt.show()
```

gives:

[image: correct]

In the updated example I know the `ys` actually has a maximum of ~85, the offset was just to demonstrate proper axis enforcement.

Comment: Mmm... It still seems to be "cutting" the Y axis if there's no data around Y=0 or Y=70

Comment: woops! just flip the order of `plt.axis('image')` and `plt.axis([0, 50, 0, 70])`.  I'll edit my answer.